# implementing concatenation of attributes into a instant variables while writing a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, concatenation

I'm creating a constructor to initialize my instance variables.

An instance variable `id` should be concatenation of three attributes `id` + `memberId` + `borrowDate`.

How do I implement a concatenation of three attributes into an `id` instance variable in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

//Main.java

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person(1, 12, new Date());

        System.out.println(p.getId());


    }


}
```

//Person.java

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Person{
    private String id;

    public Person(int attrId, int id, Date borrowDate){
        this.id = String.valueOf(attrId) + String.valueOf(id) + String.valueOf(borrowDate);
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

This uses a parameterized constructor to accept values. Those parameters are then concatenated and new value is assigned to private field. I've used default Date format. You can parse it according to the format required.